# Rummikub Joker Question

Tags: rummikub

So let’s say I have a blue 11, joker and blue 13. Can I use that set of 3, tag it to the end of a blue 10, 9 & 8 thats already on the table and use the blue 13 to a different set? So I’m not replacing the joker but I’m using the set of 3 it’s apart of.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can combine sets into new sets. As long as you follow the rules. That is the fun part of the game.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rummikub):

> **Joker substitution**:
>   A set containing a joker can have tiles added to it, be split apart or have tiles removed from it. The joker can be moved or replaced in any possible way as long as you maintain a set of at least three tiles.

Answer (score 0):

Any Joker tile on the table can be reused if all plays made to reorganize tiles leave legal sets of three or more tiles. Thus, if the 13 has a place to go, then you can use the Joker as you wish. One caveat, you cannot do this if you have not yet played your first meld (set).

[Rumikub Tournament Rules](https://tournaments.lfg-aus.com.au/rummikub.html)

> A joker cannot be retrieved before a player has laid down their initial meld. A joker can be retrieved from a set on the table by any player who can replace it with another tile of the same numerical and color value it represents. The tile used to replace the joker can be taken from the table or from the player's rack.